# how to build Hangout url?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm writing an add-on for [hipchat](https://www.atlassian.com/en/software/hipchat). So, basically, I want:

1. Enter in a chat room with several users (@user1, @user2, @user3, @myuser)
2. Write the message **/hangout @user1 @user3** into messages input
3. Press enter
4. See (as a new message) a **hangout url** to strat the hangout with @user1 and @user3

I don't need help to show the message (step 4), I just need to know how to build the hangout url. I need something like:

`https://plus.google.com/hangouts?users[0]=user1@gmail.com&users[1]=user3@gmail.com`

I know that I can start a HO accessing: http://hangouts.google.com/start
But, I dont want this. **I want the result url** of http://hangouts.google.com/start. I want this: https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/xxxoiiasdioasodnahsdhasd and, if it's posible with user's invitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct URL to use for starting Hangouts. Your best option is to give the user a URL on your own site that renders a [Hangout Button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) with the people to invite specified.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <title>Hangout button demo: Inviting people</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : '1234', invite_type : 'PROFILE' },
                  { id : 'foo@example.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Over two years and there is still no other way

Comment: Is there any way to do this with conversations? (AKA, chat).

Answer (score 2):

For example, use a structure like this:

> https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/OrganizationDomain.com/group-name

**Where:**

- ***OrganizationDomain.com***: Is the organization domain name that will host the hangout group conversation. (*In your specific case it could be same domain used to login on HipChat.*)
- ***group-name***:  Can be a permanent hangout group, created previously. Or a new group to be created automatically.

**Notes:**

Remember that OrganizationDomain.com must be managed by [Google G Suite](http://gsuite.google.com/gsuite%E2%80%8E) in order to allow automatic group creation. Also, take a look at [how to start a group conversation](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111943).